# Process gets hung up and unable to stop-process or terminate in Powershell

Tags: r, powershell, cmd, rstudio

I am new to Powershell and CMD scripting and hope you can help.  I am running code in R which includes using the shell command to run a batch file that opens and runs a process in another program, Quest Analytics. I notice that this kicks off a process in my Task Manager called "QuestConsole.exe."  Quest does some stuff then saves a file to my C drive and is supposed to close.  However, it does not always close and remains hung up with the memory usage showing no change.  R will not commence with the rest of my code until I actually force the process closed in Task Manager.  I have no problem closing it that way and R then picks up where it left off with no issues.  I am designing this to run autonomously through a shiny app so won't be able to use Task Manager to close it every time it gets hung up. So I decided to try building a Powershell script that runs continuously in the background and kills the QuestConsole.exe process if it has been active for more than 6 minutes.

I've tried 2 different approaches in Powershell:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter “name = ‘QuestConsole.exe’”).Terminate()
```

and

```
Stop-Process -Name QuestConsole
```

Neither of these work. There is no error.  Powershell acts like everything is fine but the QuestConsole.exe process is still in Task Manager (mocking me!).

I was able to get this to work in CMD:

```
Wmic process where name=”QuestConsole.exe” call terminate
```

I prefer to use Powershell because I have already written my script and the learning process was painful. Does anyone know any other ways to kill my process in PowerShell?  Perhaps an equivalent to the command that I used in CMD?  Also, I will include my Powershell script in case a kind soul can help me re-write it in CMD.

```
While ($True) {
$startTimeLimit = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -minutes 6)
$questStart = (Get-Process QuestConsole).StartTime
$eval = $questStart -gt $startTimeLimit
if ($eval -eq $false)
{
    Stop-Process -Name QuestConsole
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good reason why `Stop-Process -Name QuestConsole` shouldn't work.

That said, pragmatically speaking, if the `wmic.exe` command works for you, just call it from PowerShell.

Additionally, you shouldn't run your monitoring script in a tight loop - sleep between checks; therefore:

```
While ($True) {
  if (((Get-Date) - (Get-Process QuestConsole).StartTime).TotalMinutes -ge 6 {
     wmic process where 'name="QuestConsole.exe"' call terminate
  }
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Note the streamlined conditional and the `'...'` around the `wmic` filter argument to ensure that the `"` chars. are passed through.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @JupiterIo; my pleasure.